# ¿Qué significa “allá” en "Quizá algunos estén en pleno de vacaciones, o hayan vuelto *allá*"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

He oído esta frase en un programa de radio:

> Hola, queridos oyentes, quizá algunos estén en pleno de vacaciones, o hayan vuelto **allá**.

¿Qué significa *allá* aquí? ¿Sería “there”? Pero cuando dice “allá”, ¿no es un lugar conocido por el locutor?

Por cierto, no estoy segura de que haya oído bien lo de “allá”. Esa pronunciación la oí al principio del programa de radio. Si está mal, ¿qué palabra podría ser?

Comment: Con solo esta información puede ser complicado. Se me ocurre que el locutor es de una emisora de una ciudad determinada y que también esté de vacaciones o desplazado, y con "allá" se refiera a la ciudad de donde es la emisora. En todo caso, intuyo que tanto el locutor como los oyentes sabían en su momento a qué se refería con "allá", que aquí no creo que tenga más connotaciones que "there".

Comment: @Charlie no estoy segura que si he escuchado bien con “allá”. Esa pronunciación escuché del principio de un  programe de radio. Si está mal, qué palabra será?

Comment: En ese caso, si crees que no oíste bien la palabra, yo me atrevería a decir que la frase fue "quizá algunos estén en pleno de vacaciones, o hayan vuelto ya". Por otro lado, a mí me sonaría mejor la expresión "en plenas vacaciones".

Comment: @Charlie gracias. Voy a oír otras veces para que no haya error. Por cierto, justo corregí mi entrada para mejorala, ¿la puede repasar? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin más datos que los mostrados, yo me atrevería a decir que la frase que oíste fue la siguiente:

> Hola, queridos oyentes, quizá algunos estén en plenas vacaciones, o hayan vuelto ya.

Podría ser que el locutor hubiera dicho realmente *allá*, pero como expresé en los comentarios, se deberían dar un cúmulo de circunstancias para que fuera posible. Por ejemplo, que el locutor fuera de una emisora local y estuviera hablando desde fuera de la ciudad local de la emisora, y el público conociera ese detalle. Demasiado rebuscado porque eso además daría por cierto que la gente se va de vacaciones fuera de la ciudad.

Comment: “En plenAS vacaciones”----> si “plenAS” con forma plural es porque necesita coincidir con el vocablo plural, o sea, “vacaciones”? Y es “plena”, no “pleno” es porque “vacación” es fémina?

Comment: @Fabiola exacto. :-) Igual que se dice "en pleno verano", "a plena luz", "en plenos exámenes", etc. Siempre concuerda ya que "pleno" es un adjetivo [que significa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TPFxNYh) "que ocupa la parte central de algo".

Comment: Ya veo. Gracias!